# Equation $1+x^8y^4+x^4y^8-x^2y^4-x^6y^6-x^4y^2=0$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, algebraic-geometry

How to prove that the following equation: $$1+x^8y^4+x^4y^8-x^2y^4-x^6y^6-x^4y^2=0$$

has for solution(in real numbers): $|x|=|y|=1~$ only.

Any hint would be appreciated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Note that the proposed equation is equivalent to
$$
(1-x^2y^4)^2+(1-x^4y^2)^2+x^4y^4(x^2-y^2)^2=0
$$
So, any solution satisfies $x^2y^4=x^4y^2=1$ and $xy(x^2-y^2)=0$. This implies clearly that $x^2=y^2=1$.$\qquad\square$

Answer (score 0):

Pick any number $\alpha\neq 0$ and assume there is a solution with $y =\alpha x$, then 
the equation becomes
$$ 1-(\alpha^2+\alpha^4)y^6 + (\alpha^4-\alpha^6+\alpha^8)y^{12}=0.$$
This is a quadratic in $z=y^6$ that can be solved.  For $\alpha=\pm 1$ you get the solutions $|x|=|y|=1$, but you should also get real solutions for other values of $\alpha$.

Comment: Hint:  put multicharacter exponents in braces.  So y^{12} instead of y^12 gives $y^{12}$ instead of $y^12$  This works generally:  fractions, subscripts, etc.

Comment: Yes, indeed.  In my case the problem is that I didn't read properly what I wrote.  Sometimes one gets blind to ones own errors...  Thanks for the correction.